# MySQL Workbench Results Grid not showing returned records

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL WORKBENCH is connecting to my database, showing tables, but not showing query results.

I can see the results of the same query by running from the mysql command line interface.

I am accessing a database using my VPN connection.

I'm puzzled why WORKBENCH won't display the results.

Comment: Ooh, now I have noticed that each row can be seen by using the "Form Editor" view, so the records have been returned.

Why on earth can't they appear in the "Results Grid"?

Comment: What WB version and OS? There was a recent results view bug on Linux.

Comment: Sorry, daft of me not to post that.  6.3.4.0 build 828 64bit running on Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded latest .deb file and installed. Was prompted to update by Ubuntu Software Centre.

After re-installation/update same version ref in Help/About, but now works. Hmmm.